# How to load webhook information sent from jira?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

The information I want appears when I turn on the function marked in the red box.

[image]

The console output shows the data I want. I want to register a specific key: value in the jenkinsfile and use it in the jenkinsfile script.

That webhook has a value including issue data from jira, and I want to extract and use only the key value

Give me life... I'm working on 3 days...

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
import groovy.json.JsonSlurperClassic
node {
    stage('Example') {
        script {
            def genericTrigger = { config ->
                // def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurperClassic()
                def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()
                // def json = jsonSlurper.parseText(config)
                // def json = jsonSlurper.parseText(jsonText)
                def json = jsonSlurper.parseText("\"${config}\"")
                return json.key
            }
            def key = genericTrigger(env.CHANGES_SINCE_LAST_SUCCESS)
            echo "Jira Issue Key: ${key}"
        }
    }
}
```